# RBDMS for sqlite3 Error in insert operation..rollback

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to insert multiple records in an RBDMS table but receive the following error

```
Error in insert operation..rollback
```

Could anyone help me fix the problem? Below is the code for adding multiple records and creating the table itself

```
# Dog Table
qry='''

CREATE TABLE DOG (
        dogID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        dogFirstName TEXT (30),
        dogLastName TEXT (30),
        dogDOB DATETIME,
        clientID INTEGER (5),
        dogMedication TEXT (100),
        dogEatingRequirements TEXT (100), 
        dogBehaviour TEXT (100), 
        StaffEmail TEXT (30),
        clientEmail TEXT (30)

);

'''
try:
        cur.execute(qry)
        print ('Table created successfully')
except:
# If table already exists then use the SQLite console to connect to the database (BEMM459.db) and then use the drop table command.
# .. Altenatively, use the SQLiteStudio GUI to delete table ECC_DEPARTMENT and execute this code block again.
        print ('Error in creating table')
```

And

```
# Insert multiple records in table DOG

qry="insert into DOG (dogFirstName, dogLastName, dogDOB, clientID, dogMedication, dogEatingRequirments, dogBehaviour, staff email, clientEmail) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
doglist=[('Archie', 'Collins', '01/01/1990', 1, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'alex@eddc.co.uk', 'a@email.com'),
           ('Betsey', 'Enoch', '02/02/1990', 2, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'alex@eddc.co.uk', 'b@email.com'),
           ('Casey', 'Soper', '03/03/1990', 3, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'alex@eddc.co.uk', 'c@email.com'),
           ('Collin', 'Austins', '04/04/1990', 4, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'alex@eddc.co.uk', 'd@email.com'),
           ('Dorris', 'Rose', '05/05/1990', 5, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'alex@eddc.co.uk', 'e@email.com'),
           ('Ella', 'Clarkson', '06/06/1990', 6, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'brenda@eddc.co.uk', 'f@email.com'),
           ('Felix', 'Champion', '07/07/1990', 7, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'brenda@eddc.co.uk', 'g@email.com'),
           ('Gus', 'Hunt', '08/08/1990', 8, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'brenda@eddc.co.uk', 'h@email.com'),
           ('Herman', 'Thompson', '09/09/1990', 9, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'brenda@eddc.co.uk', 'i@email.com'),
           ('Iggy', 'Hilton', '10/19/1990', 10, 'None', 'Dry food', 'Well Behaved', 'brenda@eddc.co.uk', 'j@email.com')]

try:
        cur.executemany(qry, doglist)
        conn.commit()
        print ('Records inserted successfully..committed')
except:
        print ('Error in insert operation..rollback')
        conn.rollback()
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: What do you mean by the exception? I'm very new to this!

Comment: You catch an exception and print your own error there. If you looked at the actual exception it would tell you. Remove the try/except to see

Comment: How do I catch an exception and print my own error? Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: I removed the Remove the try/except, ran the code, but no error message has appeared

Comment: Remove the space from `staff email` in the INSERT statement.

Comment: I removed the space from `staff email` but still have the same error `Error in insert operation..rollback`

Comment: Found the bug! I copied the text in my table into my INSERT statement and the records have been inserted successfully